# Database access via Hamachi (VPN)

Tags: mysql, hamachi

I would like to access the database from a computer (PC2) connected to the network (Hamachi) I've created in my local unit (PC1). My goal is to achieve data sharing between two databases through a php program as the system for querying the databases, and the Hamachi as my VPN. I'm using SQLyog for the MySQL GUI.

Here's a map of my plan:

```
  DB1 <<--------  --------->> DB2              1. PC1 is the owner of the VPN created via Hamachi
   |           |  |            |               2. PC2 joins the PC1 in the VPN
   |       Data Sharing        |               3. Hamachi assigns IP addresses to each PC
   |           |  |            |               4. PC1 should be able to manage DB2 & vice versa
  PC1----- + HAMACHI < ------ PC2
```

So far, I am able to use the IP address assigned to each pc by the Hamachi to access the local database. Using PC1, I type in the SQLyog the PC1 Hamachi IP and the standard credentials that I use. Here's an example:
[Hamachi_network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujsO7.jpg)
[SQLyog_Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoAFH.png)

My problem is I am unable to access the DB2 in PC1. Likewise, I am unable to open DB1 with PC2. There are no problems with the VPN since I can browse the shared files of each computer. Additionally, since the assigned IP addresses work on their corresponding computer, the Hamachi can function like a server for the hosting of the system and database. The only thing left is the data sharing between the two dbs.

```
// Error message in the SQLyog:
Error No. 2003
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'hamachi_ip' (10060)
```

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to access the remote database?

Comment: This must a problem with the firewall configurations. You need to ask this questions on the superuser channel. BTW, check this link https://community.logmein.com/t5/Hamachi-Gamers-Group/Inbound-Traffic-blocked-check-firewall-settings/td-p/134642

Comment: @Shadow I've updated the post. The error message I get in the SQLyog is "Error No. 2003  Can't connect to MySQL server on 'hamachi_ip' (10060)

Comment: @Kris I'll try to check the link. What's the "superuser channel"?

Comment: visit here https://superuser.com/

Comment: @Kris thank you for the Hamachi link. It really was the firewall configurations. I'll post an answer in this question later in case some else encounters this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the link provided by Kris, I found the solution to this problem. Basically, I just need to uncheck Hamachi in the Protected Connections of Windows Firewall. (This should be applied on all PCs connected to the VPN)